# Convert string to base64 in Swift 3

Tags: swift, string, swift3, base64

```
let strsize = 10_000_000
let tries = 100
var longstring:String = "a"

for i in 1...strsize {
longstring += "a"
}

for i in 1..<2 {
let basestring = NSData(base64EncodedString: longstring, options: .IgnoreUnknownCharacters)
print(basestring)
}
```

Writing a code in command prompt. What is the correct code to write for Swift 3 which I been getting `use of unresolved identifier NSData` . Most of the tutorials on encoding string to base64 aren't working.

This is working for you on Linux or Mac?
http://studyswift.blogspot.sg/2016/03/convert-nsdatauint8-to-base64-in-swift.html

Comment: In Swift 3, most uses of `NSData` were converted to the new value type named `Data`. Do: `Data(base64Encoded: longstring, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)`

Comment: @ozgur: Not renamed, at least not on the Apple platforms, both still exist and `Data` is the "Swift overlay type" for `NSData`. But that may be different on Linux.

Comment: If you get `unresolved identifier` you forgot to `import Foundation`

Comment: Does it work on Linux with import Foundation or any resolution?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
let longstring = "test123"
if let data = (longstring).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
    let base64 = data.base64EncodedString(options: Data.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
    print(base64)// dGVzdDEyMw==\n
}
```

Comment: Hmm... Are you using Swift3.0?

Comment: Why `options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0)` is there? You can just use `[]`, if you want empty option set, and it works with all `OptionSet` types. And even more, there's `.base64EncodedString()`, which  doesn't need options to be specified.

Comment: Yes, the title indicated, it seem I need ```import Foundation```?

Comment: It won't compile unless I import that. Well, plan to submit the test for benchmark and would be easier to have it work on Linux, currently on Mac.

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved my life dear bro. thnx thx thx

Answer (score 0):

this string extention can help .

```
extension String {
    //Base64 decode
    func fromBase64() -> String? {
            guard let data = Data(base64Encoded: self) else {
                    return nil
            }
            return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    }

    //Base64 encode
    func toBase64() -> String {
            return Data(self.utf8).base64EncodedString()
    }
 }
```

how to use.

```
let str = "Hello World"
str.toBase64().fromBase64()
```

Answer (score -1):

In Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10.1

```
//Base64 encoding
let data = combinedString.data(using: .utf8)//Here combinedString is your string
let encodingString = data?.base64EncodedString()
print(encodingString!)

// OR Single line of code
let encodingString = combinedString.data(using: .utf8)?.base64EncodedString()//Here combinedString is your string
print(encodingString!)
```